# Сделать hotkey на странице

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Мне нужно задать на странице hotkey. Сейчас проблема в том, что hotkey почему-то прицепляется к конкретному компоненту и доступен только в том случае, когда фокус на нём.

```
<template>
  <v-container
    @keydown.esc="overlay = false"
    @keydown.f2="overlay = true"
  >    
    <div class="text-center">
      <v-btn
        fab
        fixed
        bottom
        right
        style="margin-bottom: 50px; margin-right: 30px;"
        @click="overlay = true"
      >
        Query
      </v-btn>

      <v-overlay :value="overlay">
        <v-row>
          <v-card min-width="1000px">
            hotkey: f2
          </v-card>
        </v-row>
      </v-overlay>
    </div>
    <v-expansion-panels
      :accordion="true"
      :inset="true"
      :multiple="true"
      :focusable="true"
      style="z-index: 0"
    >
      <v-expansion-panel
        v-for="(item,i) in 55"
        :key="i"
      >
        <v-expansion-panel-header>Item</v-expansion-panel-header>
        <v-expansion-panel-content>
          <br>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
        </v-expansion-panel-content>
      </v-expansion-panel>
    </v-expansion-panels>
    </v-container>

</template>

<script>    
  export default {
    name: "Sampler",
    data: () => ({
      overlay: false,
    }),
  }
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

Вот так выглядит страница

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если я кликаю на кнопку query, то открывается `overlay`. Если я нажимаю `Esc`, то `overlay` закрывается. Но при этом, кнопка `Query` должна быть в фокусе, т.е.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Видно, что она отличается по цвету от предыдущего случая. Если я кликну где-нибудь в стороне, то окажется, что `Esc` уже не работает. Как побороть эту проблему. Я думал, что привязав  `keydown` к родительскому компоненту, всё заработает. Но это не так.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Событие в данном случае висит на компоненте, а не на странице. Для того, чтобы повесить событие на страницу, следует сделать аналогичные действие в `mounted`:

```
mounted() {
  window.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
    if (e.code === 'F2') {
      this.overlay = true
    } else if (e.code === 'Escape') {
      this.overlay = false
    }
  });
},
```

Чтобы быть в фокусе, следует начать поле к примеру редактировать, или нажать на него.